# DB2 SQL array in attribute-defs of user defined type

Tags: sql, db2, user-defined-types

I have a question concerning user defined types in DB2(v. 9.7.0.441). I want to create a type which has an attribute-array of another user defined type. Let me show you what I mean by a brief (fictional) example:

This is the UDT I want to use in another type

```
CREATE TYPE sport AS
(
  Sport VARCHAR(10)
) MODE DB2SQL;
```

This is the UDT which should use the one above

```
CREATE TYPE person AS
(
  plays sport ARRAY[3] // 'REF(sport)' or 'plays VARCHAR(10) ARRAY[3]' don't work either  
) MODE DB2SQL;
```

DB2 just says that the token ARRAY[3] is unexpected.

Any hint what could be wrong here? By now it would be enough to have an CHAR Array in a UDT...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ok,

according to [db2's CREATE TYPE (array) statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050497.html) "an array type can only be used as the data type of:

- A local variable in a compound SQL (compiled) statement
- A parameter of an SQL routine
- A parameter of a Java procedure (ordinary arrays only)
- The returns type of an SQL function
- A global variable

and

A variable or parameter defined with an array type can only be used in compound SQL (compiled) statements
"

So its just not possible to use an array type inside a user defined type :-/

Answer (score 0):

I would assume something like the following...

```
CREATE TYPE sport AS(Sport VARCHAR(10)) MODE DB2SQL;
CREATE TYPE PersonT AS(plays SportT ARRAY[3]) MODE DB2SQL;
CREATE TYPE SportArrayT AS SportT ARRAY[3];
CREATE TYPE PersonT AS (plays SportT SportArrayT) MODE DB2SQL;
```

However, the 3rd statement fails. Obviously an array of a user-defined type (or REF(SportT)) is not allowed :-(

Comment: Welcome on SO, it is usually a good manner to not assuming anything when you are replying to a question. In that way, your post is more valuable to the community. Try to clarify your point or fix the problems. :)

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the [doc for CREATE TYPE (array)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0050497.html).

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but the examples they give are like this:

```
CREATE TYPE CAPITALSARRAY AS VARCHAR(30) ARRAY[VARCHAR(20)]
```